# Scatterplot ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import statistics
import numpy as np
states = [(d['State']) for d in data]
common_list=Counter(states).most_common(3)
first_common_temp=[d["Temperature(F)"] for d in data if d["State"] == common_list[0][0]]
FCT=[]
first_common_humid=[d["Humidity(%)"] for d in data if d["State"] == common_list[0][0]]
FCH=[]
second_common_temp=[d["Temperature(F)"] for d in data if d["State"] == common_list[1][0]]
SCT=[]
second_common_humid=[d["Humidity(%)"] for d in data if d["State"] == common_list[1][0]]
SCH=[]
third_common_temp=[d["Temperature(F)"] for d in data if d["State"] == common_list[2][0]]
TCT=[]
third_common_humid=[d["Humidity(%)"] for d in data if d["State"] == common_list[2][0]]
TCH=[]
#create six lists, three most common accident states and their corrosponding temp and humidity at time of accident, creates empty list to be filled with floats
x=0
for x in range (0, len(first_common_temp)):
    try:
        FCT.append(float(first_common_temp[x]))
    except ValueError:
        x=0
for x in range (0, len(first_common_humid)):
    try:
        FCH.append(float(first_common_humid[x]))
    except ValueError:
        x=0
for x in range (0, len(second_common_temp)):
    try:
        SCT.append(float(second_common_temp[x]))
    except ValueError:
        x=0
for x in range (0, len(second_common_humid)):
    try:
        SCH.append(float(second_common_humid[x]))
    except ValueError:
        x=0
for x in range (0, len(third_common_temp)):
    try:
        TCT.append(float(third_common_temp[x]))
    except ValueError:
        x=0
for x in range (0, len(third_common_humid)):
    try:
        TCH.append(float(third_common_humid[x]))
    except ValueError:
        x=0
#this is to make a usable list of just the filled data points, empty sets are removed
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.scatter(FCH, FCT,
           s=100,
           #size
           c="red",
           marker=".",
           alpha=0.5
           #transparency
           )
```

I am trying to plot a scatterplot using data where there is some empty data, hence the for loops creating a new list, the length of FTH and FCT are one dimensional and but vary as FCT is 5 larger, but i wouldnt imagine that I need to make one shorter?

Comment: try checking shape of each column. else provide a sample input.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I'm questioning the logic in `except ValueError: x=0`; you're setting the value of `x` to `0`, but you aren't doing anything with that zero. Did you mean to append a 0 to the list(s) in each loop?

Comment: However you create them, `FCH`, `FCT` have to have the same size.  A pair of values from each defines the location of one point on the plot.